Can IRS make the taxpayer pay the costs of litigation if the latter loses the case?
Let's say a petition is filed at tax or district court against IRS because the petitioner thinks he/she doesn't owe tax imposed by IRS or is entitled to refund but not getting one from IRS. And let's say the taxpayer loses the case.
Can IRS make the taxpayer reimburse all the court and administrative expenses incurred as a result of litigation initiated by the taxpayer?
26 U.S.C. § 7430 states that any prevailing party of a given court case may ask the judge to make the losing side reimburse the expenses incurred, but it also states that the loser may avoid paying any costs if the loser can prove that the case wasn't frivolous.
However based on my reading of the section 7430, this defense is only available to IRS as per subsection (c)(4)(B).
Does this mean that the taxpayer is likely to be liable for expenses caused to IRS as a result of litigation and there's no specific provision to use as defense?

What is likely or not will be determined by the attorney based on the specifics of the case. The IRC Sec. 7430(c)(4)(B) provides for an exception if the US shows its position was substantially justified, which means that if the taxpayer prevailed on something the IRS had a reasonable expectation of the taxpayer not prevailing based on the law and precedent - the taxpayer will likely not be awarded costs. There are a lot of other special rules, exceptions, and precedents.
So the answer to your question in the subject, in general, is yes. Specifically to each case - facts need to be evaluated by a competent attorney.

I think this answers a different question

Admittedly the OP asks multiple questions in the post, so I'm focusing selectively on what is answerable

You are correct - I was focused on the question in the title.
